# Lagrangian and Hamiltonian Mechanics

Tags: reference-request, math-history, classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

I am interested in how Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics and then symplectic geometry was developed starting from Newtonian mechanics. We can start by assuming that Newtonian mechanics tells us that motion of a particle under an applied force is a second order differential equation in the configuration space. I know that first Lagrangian mechanics was developed and then Hamiltonian mechanics.

I guess in formulating Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics, they were motivated by optics and variational ideas within. Infact in Arnold's book he gives a sketch of the idea showing that every concept in Huygen's Optics has an analogy in Hamiltonian mechanics. Yet I do not understand the physical or mathematical motivation why people wanted to formulate mechanics like optics?

After this point I guess it is not so hard to pass to symplectic geometry and cotangent bundles. Indeed one can see that a set of canonical transformations for Hamiltonian systems on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the one which is the transition functions for the space of differential 1-forms (i.e cotangent space). From here I think it is evident why one should formulate Hamiltonian mechanics on the cotangent space.

Comment: Not an answer, but more a general comment. If you're interested in this sort of thing, it can be very rewarding to read the actual historic papers. See for example: http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/Rays/PtFst.pdf .

Comment: And: http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/Dynamics/GenMeth.pdf.

Comment: thanks, indeed such references should be very useful